# Can't add plugins to project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I'm working through [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/Developer) tutorial, which deals with adding a maven plugin to a java project.

I follow the tutorial smoothly to [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/Developer#Add_the_plugin_to_the_OM2M_product.28s.29) step, where it says, that my plugin's state is STARTING instead of RESOLVED (like in the tutorial's picture):

[image]

I don't know if this has anything to do with my main problem which is the next step - [Adding the plugin dependencies](http://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/Developer#Add_plugin_dependencies). There are 6 plugin dependencies shown in the tutorial, and I can only add the first three. Using the search box, I can't find these plugins:

- org.eclipse.om2m.commons
- org.eclipse.om2m.ipu.service
- org.eclipse.om2m.core.service

I can see that the missing plugins are located in the main project (the project to which I'm adding my plugin). I probably did something wrong a long the way, so it isn't even searching for them, but since I have zero experience with plugins I don't even know where to start looking.

Can anybody shed some light on what could be the problem?

[image]